# Unable to create new Database and Collection at runtime in cosmodb while writing Spark Dataframe to Cosmodb (SQL Api) using Spark-CosmosDB Connector

Tags: apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using Apache Spark 2.3.2v. Below is my use case to perform with CosmosDB using Apache Spark.
I am using **azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11_1.3.3** connector.

**Use case** - I am performing some complex aggregation in spark and my data is in CosmosDB(SQL). I want to read the data from CosmosDB in Apache Spark data-frame and perform some complex aggregations function and write back into CosmosDB storing in new Database and Collection which will create at Runtime.

I am able to read the data from CosmosDB successfully and performed my functions with data-frame.
Now i want to write back into CosmosDB but in new Database and new Collection.

Below is my code to read data from CosmosDB -

```
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.schema._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config

val readConfig = Config(Map("Endpoint" -> "https://xyz.documents.azure.com:443/",
    "Masterkey" -> "",
    "Database" -> "Database1",
    "PreferredRegions" -> "",
    "Collection" -> "Collection1",
    "SamplingRatio" -> "1.0"))

val flights = spark.read.cosmosDB(readConfig)
    flights.count()   // performed complex aggrgate functions
```

Below is code to write back to CosmosDB (new Database and Collection) -

```
val writeConfig = Config(Map(
    "Endpoint" -> "https://xyz.documents.azure.com:443/",
    "Masterkey" ->"",
    "Database" -> "Database2",
    "PreferredRegions" -> "",
    "Collection" -> "Collection2",
    "WritingBatchSize" -> "100",
    "Upsert" -> "true"))

   flights.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).cosmosDB(writeConfig)
```

When i try to give different database and new Collection name (not created in cosmosDb) it always give me below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException: Message:      {"Errors":["Resource Not Found. Learn more: https:\/\/aka.ms\/cosmosdb-tsg-not-found"]}
```

I looked in many links but all are giving the database name and collection name same to read write operation.
Please let me know if you need any inputs.

Query -

1. Can i create a Database and Collection in CosmosDB through Apache spark using Spark-cosmos Db connector?

Please suggest me any solution. Do i need to build an API as similar as it is in .NET SDK

Comment: Are you using the read only key instead of the read write key by any chance? Could you please check and confirm?

Comment: I am using Read Write key. I tried with both primary and secondary key. But whenever i give a new Container name inside the database in code it gives me mentioned exception.